# Need help installing 14.04 Trusty from USB drive (OLD PC)

Tags: ubuntu, usb

I have a friend with an IBM ThinkPad T30, and I'm trying to help him install Ubuntu MATE 14.04 Trusty Tahr from a USB drive. He's gone into the BIOS and changed all the necessary settings, and it goes into the "Intel Boot Agent", then says that it can't find an OS on the USB stick. He used UNetbootin to create the drive from the .ISO image downloaded from the UM website.

Comment: It's possible the computer may not see the USB device I had a computer that was stubborn like that once and had to do an install with a disc. Can you make a bootable disc or is the only way you can do it with a USB?

Answer (score 0):

Try using Rufus and select the MBR only option in the drop down box for specifying the bootable type. On that particular model you need to go into the BIOS using the F1 key and manually setting the USB drive to the first priority (must be plugged in before powering on the machine).